# Rails: find where nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

My product index returns all products but I only want the ones that have photos.

Controller:

```
@products = Product.all.includes(:photos)
```

Models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :photos
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, allow_destroy: true
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Schema:

```
  create_table "photos", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "photos", ["product_id"], name: "index_photos_on_product_id", using: :btree
  add_index "photos", ["user_id"], name: "index_photos_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "products", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "price"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.boolean  "sold",             default: false
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to fetch `products` that have at least one `photo`? Use an inner-join like so:

```
@products = Product.
            joins(:photos).
            where(products: {sold: false}).
            group("products.id")
```

That is the best way, IMO.

But (just to show you what is possible) you could also fetch `products` that have IDs in the `photos` table.

```
product_ids = Photo.pluck("DISTINCT product_id")
@products = Product.where(id: product_ids, sold: false)
```

Comment: By solid you mean sold? and it's sold on the product model not photo

Comment: I get this error  Product Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "photos" ON "photos"."product_id" = "products"."id" WHERE "product"."sold" = 'f' GROUP BY photos.id
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "product"
LINE 1: ... ON "photos"."product_id" = "products"."id" WHERE "product"....
                                                             ^
: SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "photos" ON "photos"."product_id" = "products"."id" WHERE "product"."sold" = 'f' GROUP BY photos.id

Comment: Look at the `sold` condition. It's `product.sold` which is wrong. I conclude that you've got a typo in your code. In your `where` condition you're typing `product: {sold: false}` but it should be `products`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this could work. .includes allows a where to be called on it.

```
Product.all.includes(:photos).where("image != ?", nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

how about a simple:

```
@products = Product.include(:photos).select{ |prod| prod.photo.present? }
```